# DataTable Sort using column number instead of column names

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I would like to sort a datatable by using the column index not with column names. I am be able to do this with SQL by using `ORDER BY 2` or `ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 DESC`.But for DB performance issues I would like to do this by using CPU performance.

So how do I do that in c# ?

Example, which is not works for me:

```
sortColumn = "3 desc, 4 desc";
dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortColumn.ToString(); 
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to sort using column index rather than name. If someone adds a column to the underlying table, or to the query, the code may sort by different columns. With column name it will still continue to work as desired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this method:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortColumn; 
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

instead of

`sortColumn = "3 desc, 4 desc";`

you can use

`sortColumn = dt.Columns[3].ColumnName + " DESC," + dt.Columns[4].ColumnName + " DESC";`

Comment: As I said I could have     sortColumn = "3 desc, 4 desc".
So I don't have one index sometimes.

Comment: Did you try dt.Columns[3].ColumnName + " DESC," + dt.Columns[4].ColumnName + " DESC";?

Answer (score 1):

dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[index].ColumnName + " DESC";